# asp.net web.config location path with space

Tags: asp.net, web-config, windows-authentication, role-base-authorization

I'm trying to set a different authentication and authorization for folders in my intranet application (windows authentication) like below. I tried to use location tag, but it doesn't work when the folder's name contains space, otherwise anything works well.

`<location path="parentfolder/appro logistique">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <allow roles="domain\groupename"/>
          <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>`

How can I fix that?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you can replace the space with `&#032`, it may work.

Comment: I tried like that way but it didn't work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try this `<location path="&quot;parentfolder/appro logistique&quot;">`

Comment: it does not work. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried HTML encoding the URL?

i.e.

path="parentfolder/appro%20logistique">